# Is there a way to force php to use class in current namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I have some classes which use functions from each other. Take this below for example:

```
namespace app/myclass;

class FirstClass
{
    public function getSecondClass()
    {
        return SecondClass::instance();
    }
}

namespace app/myclass;

class SecondClass
{
    public function getFirstClass()
    {
        return FirstClass::instance();
    }
}
```

now i have child classes in another namespace as follows:

```
namespace front\myclass;

class FirstClass extends \app\myclass
{
    public function someMethod()
    {}
}

namespace front\myclass;

class SecondClass extends \app\myclass
{
    public function someMethod()
    {}
}
```

When i use the `instance()` method from the child class, it will return instance from the parent class. Is it possible to make it return from the same current namespace as it is?

example:

```
$myclass = new \front\myclass\FirstClass;
$instance = $myclass->getSecondClass(); \\ will return \app\myclass\SecondClass
```

I want it to return `front\myclass\SecondClass` instead without having to override the method since i have many files that should use same rule.

Comment: Are you extending the namespace or the class called myclass?

Comment: Extending the class... Erm how do you extend namespace? o.O

Comment: You `use` the namespace not extend. Like `use app\myclass;`. And namespace use backslash.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override the method in `FirstClass` because the parent method is calling a static method that explicitly specifies `SecondClass`, another solution could be to use traits, BUT I don't recommend them, IMHO they complicate staff

**EDIT**

Actually, after another thought about it, I feel that your code may need to be refactored, I smell something bad in there, I don't really see it (because I lack info about it, I dont see much of it) but I can smell highly coupled code, and/or OOP abuse, maybe a feature envy issue.

Comment: traits would not help here. I wanted to do something without having to touch the parent class (which are generated classes) but without also the need to override the method in the child class as i will have to override many function across my classes.

Comment: The parent class are generated files. I don't want to touch and modify them as when i will have to re generate them i will have codes to merge etc. So i decided to extend them and add whatever i need in the child